# Combining all rows in two columns using Join and skipping the empty rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a data like this, Rooms Name and Number of Projectors
[image]
I want to combine data in Row A with Row B

I already try combining my data using =ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",A2:A&" "&B2:B))
but the formula also joins empty space

How do I do it to match the Desired result?
ie Orchid 1, Rose 1, Dahlias 1, Tulip 2, Jasmine 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a FILTER depending on A being not empty:

```
=ArrayFormula(JOIN(", ",FILTER(A2:A&" "&B2:B,A2:A<>"")))
```

Comment: Hi Martin! This works well!
I've tried using filter but ending up in errors, my filter syntax apparently wrong that time,
Anyway do u have information on where I could learn more about advance Filter function in Google Sheets?
Many tutorials / documentation online not provide me as much, even I did not know I can use Filter function syntax as you stated above.

Thanks martin, nice day to you!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Honestly, I've learned everything here, watching how others apply FILTER. The main principles you need to know are two: 1) you can work only one direction at a time: filter by rows or filter by columns. If you need to do it with both, nest two FILTER. 2) Every condition you need to set is basically a bunch of 1s and 0s (or TRUE and FALSE). So what you always need is to get there: to a matching size array of 1s and 0s. For example: =FILTER(A1:E10,{1,0,1,0,1}) will filter columns A, C and E

Comment: With these concepts, you can use BYROW, MAP, or even other functions with the help of INDEX or ARRAYFORMULA. Easy case: =FILTER(A2:E,A2:A<>""), even with other column not included in range: =FILTER(A2:E,Z2:Z<>""). With BYROW: filtering rows that sum more than 20 between columns C and F: =FILTER(A2:M,BYROW(C2:F,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r)>=20))). Other option with MATCH: You want to filter depending on a name in B being found in I2;I20: =FILTER(A2:C,INDEX(IFNA(MATCH(B2:B,I2:I20,0 ))>0)) and so on. Hope it's helpful as lenses to read or find other true tutorials (not like this, he)

Answer (score 0):

You may try `BYROW()` then `JOIN()`.

```
=JOIN(", ",BYROW(A2:INDEX(A2:B,COUNTA(A2:A)),LAMBDA(x,JOIN(" ",x))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harun! Tahnks for yout answers!
Buat apparently I try martin answer below and it works well.
I will learn more about BYROW Function and LAMBDA,
Thanks!

Comment: @Idad Yes, Martin's answer is good enough but array formulas take more time to process. Rather than `FILTER()` function `QUERY()` will be faster.

Comment: Agree with @Harun24hr - I used FILTER because I was not sure if A column would have consecutive values, or if there would be only one type of data per column (which is the main limitation with QUERY)